# Blender Quadro p1000 disapears in 2.92 and reappears in 2.80

Tags: gpu

I recently purchased a Quadro P1000 and installed it into my system running MX Linux. I installed Blender through the MX Package Manager(they only provide 2.80), the card was recognized and work perfectly. I decide to download 2.92 from flatpak and noticed my P1000 was showing "no compatible GPUs found" in the System menu. The strange part is, the only way I can get my P1000 to show in 2.92 is only If I open 2.80 go to the system menu(which my gpu is showing and being recognized) select CUDA and close 2.80. Now if I launch 2.92 my GPU is recognized. Also if the computer goes to sleep both 2.80 and 2.92 do not recognize my GPU and I'll need to restart and go through the process all over again.

I installed the nvidia drivers through the "Nvidia driver installer" tool and also installed the CUDA Toolkit, I've removed them and reinstalled many times. Hoping someone has an idea of what I can do to fix this issue.

Thank you